# CakePHP 3.0 - How to create a postLink with confirmMessage?

Tags: cakephp, form-helpers, cakephp-3.0

I started working in CakePHP 3.0 (beta) today.

In CakePHP 2.0 there was an option for adding a confirm message to a postlink. This would result in an alert when clicking on the link.

More info about the postLink in CakePHP 2.0:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#FormHelper::postLink

More info about the postLink in CakePHP 3.0:
[http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#Cake\View\Helper\FormHelper::postLink](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#Cake%5CView%5CHelper%5CFormHelper::postLink)

In the 3.0 version the confirmMessage is gone. Does anybody know if CakePHP 3.0 has an alternative for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not gone, it was just moved into an option named `confirm`:

```
$this->Form->postLink('title', 'url', ['confirm' => 'Are you sure?'])
```

See also **http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.View.Helper.FormHelper.html#_postLink**

Comment: Thank you! How did you find it? I looked in the CakePHP 3.0 cookbook but it wasn't there.

Comment: You should also read the migration guide - it states the change, as well: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/appendices/3-0-migration-guide.html